# Google Translate API different translations

Tags: api, google-translate

I have got a tiny problem with the Google Detect API 2.0.

When i enter 'hostess bier' into http://translate.google.com (from a german desktop PC), Google detects German language.

When I use the Google translate detect API, I receive English language.

It must have to do something IP origin. I already tried via Proxy with an American and a German IP on my Desktop PC, and it differs.

Is there any possibly to tell Google that my origin is in Germany? I cannot change the IP of the server.